# How to preload child conditionally based on parent column?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm able to preload all `Guests` related to `Order` using this syntax:

```
Table(order).
Preload("Guests").
Where("order.code = ?", orderCode).
First(&order).
Error
```

Is it possible to to preload `Guests` based on a condition on a column in `Order` table? here is SQL for what I want to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE code = "xyz"
SELECT * FROM guests WHERE (order_id IN (1)) AND (some_column_in_guest_tbl = some_column_in_order_tbl)
```

**Note:**

I'm aware of this Preload syntax (this doesn't take value from order table column, it only works if I provide value myself):

```
Preload("Guests", "some_column_in_guest_tbl = ?", some_column_in_order_tbl)
```

Comment: Your given sql don't fetch `order` , but you want to fetch it also. Right ?

Comment: @AbinashGhosh yes I want `order` as well, just updated the SQL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Custom Preloading SQL in Gorm

**Example**: Preload guests order by name desc.

```golang
    db.Where("code = ?", orderCode).Preload("Guests", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Order("guests.name DESC")
    }).Find(&orders)
    //// SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders.code = "ABC";
    //// SELECT * FROM guests WHERE order_id IN (1,2,3,4) order by guests.name DESC;
```

For working with parent-child condition you can use `JOIN`

```golang
db.Joins("JOIN orders ON orders.id = guests.order_id ").Find(&guests)
```

Combining both may work. Like

```golang
    db.Where("code = ?", orderCode).Preload("Guests", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Joins("JOIN orders ON orders.some_column_in_order_tbl = guests.some_column_in_guest_tbl")
    }).Find(&orders)
```

Comment: thank you Abinash, I completely missed that Join would also work in Preload callback :)