# How to query a many2many relationship with a Where clause on the association with go-gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following entities:

```golang
type User struct {
  ID     string
  Name   string
  Groups []Groups `gorm:"many2many:users_groups"`
}

type Groups struct {
  ID   string
  Name string
}
```

I know I can `preload` the groups using

```golang
var users []Users
db.Preload("Groups").Find(&users)
```

And I can also filter Users using

```golang
var users []Users
db.Preload("Groups").Where("name IN ?", []string{"name1", "name2"}).Find(&users)
```

This will bring all the User that have name equals "name1" or "name2"

But I cannot filter Users based on Groups

```golang
var users []Users
db.Preload("Groups", "name IN ?", []string{"groupname"}).Find(&users)
```

I expect it to bring all Users that have Group Name equal "groupname"

How can I achieve this using database only? (my database is big and I cannot load all users into memory and filter it in the application)

I opened an issue [on gorm repository](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3287) as well

Comment: You need to Join in preload callback [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60911272/4207306)

Comment: But if I do that, I'll filter the association (groups), not the users that have `group.name = groupname`

Answer (score 4):

You may fetch users by group names very easily:

```golang
db.Preload("Groups").Where("id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users_groups WHERE name IN ?)", []string{"name1", "name2"})
```

Or, a more strict way:

```golang
db.Where("id IN (?)", db.Table("users_groups").
    Select("user_id").
    Where("name IN ?", []string{"name1", "name2"}),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solve it with using `Join`.
Probably it's late for your problem but this could help folks when they have the same problem.

solution for your case would be :

```
var users []Users
db.Preload("Groups").
Joins("inner join user_groups ug on ug.user_id = user.id ").
Joins("inner join groups g on g.id= ug.user_id ").
Where("g.name IN ?", []string{"name1", "name2"}).Find(&users)
```

ref: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
db.Preload("Groups", "name IN (?)", []string{"name1", "name2"}).Find(&users)
```

(edited) this is also just filter the Groups, not the users (by there groups)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did came up with a solution of querying a gorm model containing 3-4 many 2 many relationships with filters for main model as well as filters for fields inside association.
Here `filters` type is map[string]string
`noOfAssociationFilters` stores how many associations we have found as for the first association our col name will be `id` *(field in Lawyer Model)* and for other nested queries it will be `lawyer_id` *(field name in associations)*.

```
var lawyers []models.Lawyer
var noOfAssociationFilters int = 0
var statement string = "SELECT * FROM lawyers WHERE 1=1"
if filters["experience"] != "" {
    statement += " AND `experience` = " + filters["experience"]
}
if filters["location_id"] != "" {
    statement += " AND `location_id` = " + filters["location_id"]
}
if filters["gender"] != "" {
    statement += " AND `gender` = \"" + filters["gender"] + "\""
}
if filters["practice_area_id"] != "" {
    colName := func() string {
        if noOfAssociationFilters == 0 {
            return " `id`"
        } else {
            return " `lawyer_id`"
        }
    }()
    statement += " AND" + colName + " IN ( SELECT `lawyer_id` FROM lawyer_practice_areas WHERE practice_area_id = " + filters["practice_area_id"]
    noOfAssociationFilters += 1
}
if filters["court_id"] != "" {
    colName := func() string {
        if noOfAssociationFilters == 0 {
            return "`id`"
        } else {
            return "`lawyer_id`"
        }
    }()
    statement += " AND" + colName + " IN ( SELECT `lawyer_id` FROM lawyer_courts WHERE court_id = " + filters["court_id"]
    noOfAssociationFilters += 1
}
if filters["language_id"] != "" {
    colName := func() string {
        if noOfAssociationFilters == 0 {
            return "`id`"
        } else {
            return "`lawyer_id`"
        }
    }()
    statement += " AND" + colName + " IN ( SELECT `lawyer_id` FROM lawyer_languages WHERE language_id = " + filters["language_id"]
    noOfAssociationFilters += 1
}
for i := 0; i < noOfAssociationFilters; i++ {
    statement += ")"
}
statement += ";"
fmt.Println(statement)
result := db.Raw(statement).Find(&lawyers)
fmt.Println("RowsAffected", result.RowsAffected)
```

I have tested the solution and it was working fine for me. It generates the complete statement you need in the end based upon your filter requirements. If you pass a filter then it generates a statement for that.
It generates statements like these:-

1. **SELECT * FROM lawyers WHERE 1=1 AND `experience` = 5 AND `location_id` = 4 AND `gender` = "female" AND `id` IN ( SELECT `lawyer_id` FROM `lawyer_practice_areas` WHERE `practice_area_id` = 3 AND`lawyer_id` IN ( SELECT `lawyer_id` FROM `lawyer_courts` WHERE `court_id` = 3));**
2. **SELECT * FROM lawyers WHERE 1=1 AND `experience` = 5 AND `location_id` = 4 AND `gender` = "female";**

By this logic we can generate nested queries and get required data for m2m relations.

For reference this was my Lawyer Model

```
type Lawyer struct {
ID               uint                 `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`
FirstName        string               `gorm:"type:varchar(100) not null" json:"first_name"`
LastName         string               `gorm:"type:varchar(100) not null" json:"last_name"`
FullName         string               `gorm:"->;type:text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(first_name,' ',last_name)) VIRTUAL;" json:"full_name"`
LocationID       uint                 `gorm:"not null" json:"location_id"`
Location         Location             `gorm:"foreignKey:location_id" json:"location"`
Email            string               `gorm:"unique;not null" json:"email"`
Phone            string               `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null" json:"phone"`
Password         string               `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null" json:"password"`
ImageURL         string               `gorm:"type:text" json:"image_url"`
Education        string               `gorm:"not null" json:"education"`
Experience       uint                 `gorm:"not null" json:"experience"`
Verified         bool                 `gorm:"not null" json:"verified"`
Gender           string               `gorm:"not null" json:"gender"`
Reviews          []Review             `gorm:"foreignKey:LawyerID" json:"reviews"`
Courts           []Court              `gorm:"many2many:lawyer_courts" json:"courts"`
Languages        []Language           `gorm:"many2many:lawyer_languages" json:"languages"`
PracticeAreas    []LawyerPracticeArea `gorm:"foreignKey:LawyerID" json:"practice_areas"` }
```

And one of the many2many association was of this type

```
type LawyerPracticeArea struct {
ID             uint         `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`
LawyerID       uint         `gorm:"not null" json:"lawyer_id"`
Lawyer         Lawyer       `gorm:"foreignKey:LawyerID" json:"lawyer"`
PracticeAreaID uint         `gorm:"not null" json:"practice_area_id"`
PracticeArea   PracticeArea `gorm:"foreignKey:PracticeAreaID" json:"practice_area"`
Charge         int          `gorm:"" json:"charge"`
CreatedAt      time.Time    `json:"created_at"`
UpdatedAt      time.Time    `json:"updated_at"` }
```

Upvote if you found this helpful :) !!